# Getting only a straight line on a Shiny app plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a data frame named datatest with 3 columns (first one named Date containing dates (in order) in a character format and the other two containing numerical values (number of hits), respectively named Hits1 and Hits2). I want to create a Shiny app where I selected either Hits1 or Hits2 and it shows me the number of hits as a function of the date.

When I run the code below I get no error message but the graph shows only a flat line...

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)        

ui <- fluidPage(    

      # Generate a row with a sidebar
      sidebarLayout(      

        # Define the sidebar with one input
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("word", "Word", 
                      choices=c('Hits1','Hits2'),
                      selected='Hits1'
          )),

      # Create a spot for the lineplot
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput(outputId="lineplot")  
      )
    ))


    # Define a server for the Shiny app
    server <- function(input, output) {

      # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
      output$lineplot <- renderPlot({

        # Render a lineplot
        ggplot(datatest, aes(x=Date, y=input$word, group=1)) + geom_line()
      })
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I really don't understand where the problem is as when I simply run the ggplot line the graph is correct

```
ggplot(datatest, aes(x=Date, y=Hits1,group=1)) + geom_line()
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that when you type it into the command line, you're passing in the y variable as `y=Hits1`, but in the Shiny app `input$word` is a string, so it's `y="Hits1"`.

In ggplot, `aes_` is created for passing in strings rather than declaring it directly ([see here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html)). You will also need to add `as.name` to convert each string into a `name` object (something that R knows is referring to the variable in the dataset).

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)        

ui <- fluidPage(    

  # Generate a row with a sidebar
  sidebarLayout(      

    # Define the sidebar with one input
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("word", "Word", 
                  choices=c('Hits1','Hits2'),
                  selected='Hits1'
      )),

  # Create a spot for the lineplot
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput(outputId="lineplot")  
  )
))


# Define a server for the Shiny app
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
  output$lineplot <- renderPlot({

    # Render a lineplot
    ggplot(datatest, aes_(x=as.name("Date"), y=as.name(input$word), group=1)) + geom_line()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```